# Hiding links with hasClass()

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this list

```
<div id="sideMenu">
    <li class="page_item page_item_has_children"></li>
    <li class="page_item page_item_has_children">
        <ul class="children">
            <li></li>
            <li></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="page_item page_item_has_children"></li>
    <li class="page_item page_item_has_children current_page_parent">
        <ul class="children">
            <li></li>
            <li></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</div>
```

The class 'current_page_parent' is the page I'm in.

But I want  to hide all '.children' when you are not in '.current_page_parent'.

I made this jQuery script :

```
$(function() {
    var has_children = $('#sideMenu ul li').hasClass('page_item_has_children');
    var current_page = $('#sideMenu ul li').hasClass('current_page_parent');

    if (has_children) {
        $('.children').hide();
    } else if (current_page) {
        $('.children').show();
    }
});
```

When I load the page, all '.children' appear..

Thanks for the help

Comment: You are missing a `ul`. sideMenu should be `ul` and your selector should probably be `$('ul#sideMenu li')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like I mentioned in my comment your HTML markup is not quite right. If you are looking to solve this using your JavaScript approach vs CSS (*like Rory McCrossan mentioned and which is the better solution in most cases IMO*). Then you just need to tweak a couple things..

**HTML:**

```
<ul id="sideMenu">
    <li class="page_item page_item_has_children">parent</li>
    <li class="page_item page_item_has_children">
        parent
        <ul class="children">
            <li>test 1</li>
            <li>test 2</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="page_item page_item_has_children">parent</li>
    <li class="page_item current_page_parent">
        parent
        <ul class="children">
            <li>test a</li>
            <li>test b</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

**JS:**

```
$(function() {
    var has_children = $('ul#sideMenu li').hasClass('page_item_has_children');
    var current_page = $('ul#sideMenu  li').hasClass('current_page_parent');

    if (has_children) {
        $('.page_item_has_children .children').hide();
    } else if (current_page) {
        $('.current_page_parent .children').show();
    }
});
```

Note: I changed some of the selectors. `$('ul#sideMenu li')` to match the markup change. And scoped the `.children` classes inside the if else to their appropriate use case.

**Demo:**

http://jsfiddle.net/tdnLa532/

Comment: It works but I've forgotone thing, I've another ul.children into a li from ul.children

Answer (score 5):

Aside from your JS logic being a little off, you can achieve this in CSS alone:

```
.children {
    display: none;
}
.current_page_parent .children {
    display: block;
}
```

Then all you need to do is toggle the `current_page_parent` class on the required `li` elements.

Answer (score 0):

Found it.

You forgot to write the `<ul>` in the div. 
Add the ul in the div and it should be good.

The smallest errors are the hardest to find :)

Answer (score 0):

This will hide the `.children` when there is no `.children` inside `#sideMenu`.

```
$('.children').toggle(!(!!$('#sideMenu .children').length));
```